# C# getting 500 error from server when uploading multipartform with image to API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

So I have a management application where a user can add a product to the database through the API. The functions in the API work fine because I have tested this with postman. However, I am probably uploading it incorrectly to the Web API, and I don't know why.

The Web API is an ASP.NET CORE Web API. Ans my management is a Windows Forms application, yes I know it's not the best choice. But anyways here is how I try to upload the form to the Web API from the application:

The upload action of the form:

```
        private void buttonToevoegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textArtikelNaam.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Artikelnaam is leeg, voeg text toe", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        else if (textArtikelOmschrijving.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Artikel omschrijving is leeg, voeg text toe", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        else if (textArtikelPrijs.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Artikel prijs, voeg text toe", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        else if (comboBoxType.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selecteer type", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        else if (buttonSelecteerAfbeelding.Text == "")//werkt nog niet
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selecteer afbeelding", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        else
        {
            ToevoegProduct product = new ToevoegProduct();
            product.ProductNaam = textArtikelNaam.Text;
            product.ProductPrijs = Convert.ToInt32(textArtikelPrijs.Text);
            product.ProductBeschrijving = textArtikelOmschrijving.Text;
            product.ProductType = comboBoxType.Text;
            product.ProductAfbeelding = imageArtikel.Image;
            product.ProductWinkel = 1;
            product.ProductDirectLeverbaar = false; //niet nodig.
            product.ProductKorting = 0;
            product.ProductVoorraad = 1;
            API.postProductMulti("products", product, "toevoegen");
            MessageBox.Show("Product is correct toegevoegd!", "Gelukt!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            ProductenOverzicht f7 = new ProductenOverzicht();
            Hide();
            f7.Show();
        }
```

the API class function:

```
    public static async void postProductMulti(string model, Models.ToevoegProduct product, string optionalRoute = null)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        // create the communication to the model from the API.
        string apiposturl = apiurl;
        apiposturl += model;

        if (optionalRoute != null)
            apiposturl += ("/" + optionalRoute);

        byte[] bytes;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            product.ProductAfbeelding.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        mfdc.Add(new StringContent(product.ProductNaam), "productNaam");
        mfdc.Add(new StringContent(product.ProductPrijs.ToString()), "productPrijs");
        mfdc.Add(new StringContent(product.ProductBeschrijving), "productBeschrijving");
        mfdc.Add(new StringContent(product.ProductType), "productType");
        mfdc.Add(new StringContent(product.ProductKorting.ToString()), "productKorting");
        mfdc.Add(new StringContent(product.ProductVoorraad.ToString()), "productVoorraad");
        mfdc.Add(new StringContent(product.ProductDirectLeverbaar.ToString()), "productDirectLeverbaar");
        mfdc.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes, 0, bytes.Length), "productAfbeelding");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiposturl, mfdc);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        client.Dispose();
        string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

And this is my ToevoegProduct model:

```
namespace FlowerPower.Models
{
class ToevoegProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductNaam { get; set; }
    public int ProductPrijs { get; set; }
    public string ProductBeschrijving { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public int ProductKorting { get; set; }
    public int ProductVoorraad { get; set; }
    public bool ProductDirectLeverbaar { get; set; }
    public Image ProductAfbeelding { get; set; }
    public int ProductWinkel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my this is what my API will be doing when this action is requested:

The add action in the product controller:

```
    [HttpPost("toevoegen")]
    [EnableCors("AllowAnyOrigin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostProduct([FromForm] AddedProduct product)
    {
        // Kijk of het huidige model geldig is.
        // Zo niet dan wordt een een BadRequest code weergegeven.
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // Upload de meegegeven afbeelding naar de website en database.
        FileUploader.UploadFile(product.ProductAfbeelding);

        // Voeg het product toe aan de database.
        _context.Product.Add(ConvertAddedToProduct(product, FileUploader.UploadedUrl)[0]);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Ga naar GetProduct, dit stuurt het aangemaakte product terug.
        return CreatedAtAction("GetProduct", new { id = product.Id }, product);
    }
```

And this is the addedproduct model in my API.

```
    public class AddedProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductNaam { get; set; }
    public int ProductPrijs { get; set; }
    public string ProductBeschrijving { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public int ProductKorting { get; set; }
    public int ProductVoorraad { get; set; }
    public bool ProductDirectLeverbaar { get; set; }
    public IFormFile ProductAfbeelding { get; set; }
    public int ProductWinkel { get; set; }
}
```

I also don't want to change up my API because I know that it works and that it's possible.

As requested my postman:

[image]

And this is the exception:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException occurred
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
>     Source=
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
>      at FlowerPower.API.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\beren\Source\Repos\FlowerPowerAPI\FlowerPower1\API.cs:line 133

Comment: Can you post the exception and stack trace from the server?

Comment: Looking at your code, I suspect you need `FormUrlEncodedContent` containing all of your form values, as opposed to lots of `StringContent` parts. I could be more certain of this if I could see the working Postman request and response.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of postman and the exception which I got

Comment: I can't guarantee it will work, but please try what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: what is the code on line 133 of API.cs

Comment: @bilpor `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`

Comment: @john I saw that FormUrlEncodedContent uses strings, how will this work with the API which contains a model with a IFormFile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this issue with another solution. I used RestSharper, because that is what postman uses for C#. With the use of RestSharper came a couple of changes. I had to change the post function in my API class and the way how I was filling my model.

This is how I'm filling my model now:

```
        else
        {
            ToevoegProduct product = new ToevoegProduct();
            product.ProductNaam = textArtikelNaam.Text;
            product.ProductPrijs = Convert.ToInt32(textArtikelPrijs.Text);
            product.ProductBeschrijving = textArtikelOmschrijving.Text;
            product.ProductType = comboBoxType.Text;
            product.ProductAfbeelding = imageArtikel.ImageLocation;
            product.ProductWinkel = 1;
            product.ProductDirectLeverbaar = false; //niet nodig.
            product.ProductKorting = 0;
            product.ProductVoorraad = 1;
            API.postProductMulti("products", product, "toevoegen");
            MessageBox.Show("Product is correct toegevoegd!", "Gelukt!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            ProductenOverzicht f7 = new ProductenOverzicht();
            Hide();
            f7.Show();
        }
```

and this is the post method in the API class of the client:

```
    public static void postProductMulti(string model, Models.ToevoegProduct product, string optionalRoute = null)
    {
        //HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        // create the communication to the model from the API.
        string apiposturl = apiurl;
        apiposturl += model;

        if (optionalRoute != null)
            apiposturl += ("/" + optionalRoute);

        var client = new RestClient(apiposturl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        // Zet de headers voor de request.
        // Dit is bij alles hetzelfde met een multipart/form-data requeset.
        request.AddHeader("postman-token", "293a9ff3-e250-e688-e20d-5d16ea635597");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        // Vul de parameters met de waardes van heet model.
        request.AddParameter("productNaam", product.ProductNaam);
        request.AddParameter("productBeschrijving", product.ProductBeschrijving);
        request.AddParameter("productType", product.ProductType);
        request.AddParameter("productKorting", product.ProductKorting);
        request.AddParameter("productVoorraad", product.ProductVoorraad);
        request.AddParameter("productDirectLeverbaar", product.ProductDirectLeverbaar);
        request.AddFile("productAfbeelding", product.ProductAfbeelding); // Voeg hier het bestandspad in.
        request.AddParameter("productWinkel", product.ProductWinkel);

        // Verstuur de request.
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

This solved my problem.